# Определение-уточнение - выделять ли запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли выделять запятыми такие определения:
Мы, как учителя, обязаны следить за качеством образования.
И меняется ли что-то, если переставить слова:
Как учителя, мы обязаны следить...

Answer (score 2):

Это не просто определение, это приложение. (Мы, будучи учителями,...)Если приложение относится к личному местоимению, оно обосабливается с двух сторон. Перестановка приложения не влечёт за собой отмену обособления.

Comment: Благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 0):

От перестановки приложения меняется акцент в предложении.А знаки остаются.